# Best way to set an erray to empty within the parameters of another class

Tags: java, arrays, list, class

This class is where I want to call the arrays and set the arrays to empty within the parameters

```
public class ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier {
        private int currentMonth;
        private int currentYear;
        private String rangeOfProducts;
        private CustomerDetailsList details; //Contains the customer details array
        private PurchaseOrderList pal; //Contains the purchase array

        public ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier(int currentMonth, int currentYear,
                String rangeOfProducts ) {
            this.currentMonth = currentMonth;
            this.currentYear = currentYear;
            this.rangeOfProducts = rangeOfProducts;  
        }
    }
```

This is the class where the array is created. It pulls information from a separate class called PurchaseOrder and then sets the list.

```
public class PurchaseOrderList {

    private ArrayList<PurchaseOrder> purchaseCollection;

    public PurchaseOrderList() {
        purchaseCollection = new ArrayList<PurchaseOrder>();
    }
```

The CustomerDetailsList class is essentially the same. Just not sure as to the best way to set the array to empty when called in the ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `when called` and `within the parameters`

Comment: So I want to bring an instance of the array into the ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier within the parameters and set it to empty

Comment: Maybe I'm just saying it wrong. What is the best way to empty the array in another class without calling an empty array method?

Comment: Why don't you want to call the clear() method? Assigning a new ArrayList is
always an option.

Comment: Also, why bother with PurchaseOrderList if it just contains a List of PurchaseOrders, why not just have that on ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier?

Comment: PurchaseOrderList contains other methods as well, I was just showing it creating the array. I wanted to know what's the best possible way of emptying the array within this class. I could use  pal.clearArray(); for the PurchaseOrderList array, but I just wasn't sure if that's the best way to go about it.

Comment: It is. Why do you think, that this solution isn't suited?

Comment: public void clearArray() {
        this.purchaseCollection.clear();
    }

Comment: That's the clear method I have

Comment: And why empty someone else's array when you could just create your own? Question remains obscure.

Comment: Its not someone else's array. The array is just stored in another class. I want to empty it here

Comment: One way would be to make the field non-private. Or, as you did, with a public clear method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap the collection's own `clear()` method with a publicly-accessible method in your PurchaseOrderClass:

```
public class PurchaseOrderList {

    private ArrayList<PurchaseOrder> purchaseCollection;

    public PurchaseOrderList() {
        purchaseCollection = new ArrayList<PurchaseOrder>();
    }

    //THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
    public void clearPurchaseCollection() {
        purchaseCollection.clear();
        //You could also accomplish the same thing by reinitializing the list:
        //purchaseCollection = new ArrayList<PurchaseOrder>();
    }

}
```

Note however, that calling `new PurchaseOrderList()` already guarantees an empty `purchaseCollection` list, since you initialize it in the constructor that way.

So the only time you would need to call `clearPurchaseCollection()` is if you are reusing this object and want to clean it out first.  Depending on the rest of your application, that may be necessary, but it may also just be simpler to throw away that instance and create a `new PurchaseOrderList()`.  Totally depends on the situation.

Comment: Good answer. Might be worth mentioning that it hides the internals of the collection within PurchaseOrderList. If the collection is changed to a Set say, the client code remains intact and simply calls clearPurchaseCollection(). It may also be worth stating that it is important that PurchaseOrderList never leaks a reference to the internal collection.

Comment: Oh brilliant. So how would I make it so the arrays are to be used in this class? Because I have already created an object of the classes that contain them, such private CustomerDetailsList details; (Or how do I Initialize them)

Comment: @SmallLegend: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I think you're asking how you would initialize the internal collection(s) inside the CustomerDetailsList and the PurchaseOrderList objects.  Is that correct?